# How to Fetch API response for entered input value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an API which takes user input(username in this case) and returns the availability of username availability.

.Html file

```
Enter username: <input type="text"
id="username"
placeholder="enter username"
[(ngModel)]="user.username"
name="username">
<button (click)="getUsername()">Click me</button>
```

In the above code taking input username value as #username

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from "./http.service";
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers:[HttpService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

user = {
  username: ''
}

inputvalue:string  = this.user.username;

ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getData()
  .subscribe(
    (inputdata: Response) => console.log(inputdata.json())
  )
}

}
```

Stored input value in 'inputvalue'

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private appComponent: AppComponent) { }
getData(){
  return this.http.get("MyAPIurl/"+this.appComponent.inputvalue);
}

}
```

On the service I would like to pass the input value and append it to my API url so that I can get a response whenever user inputs a username.

Can someone correct me and let me know how does it works !

PS: I'm very new to Angular2 !

Answer (score 0):

let your `HttpService` to be more reusable:

`HttpService.getData` must accept an argument

convert your data to json before subscription

```
    import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpService } from "./http.service";
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers:[HttpService]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}

    user = {
      username: ''
    }

    inputvalue:string  = this.user.username;

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    getUsername(){
          this.httpService.getData(this.inputvalue)
              .subscribe((inputdata: any) => {
                   console.log(inputdata);
              });

    }
```

}

HttpService:

```
mport { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
getData(inputValue: string){
  return this.http
             .get("MyAPIurl/"+inputvalue)
             .map(data: Response => data.json());
}

}
```

Note : to make your code more readable rename your `HttpService` to something like `DataService`.